# MapKit annotations inconsistently deleting, don't know why

Tags: swift, swift3, mapkit, mkannotation, mapkitannotation

I am making a basic dummy app for myself because I am just starting with xcode and swift 3. 
clearLastPin function should remove the most recent pin placed. Sometimes it does but more often than not it does not.
I'm not sure where there is such inconsistency, and the same goes for clearPins, which should remove ever pin from map.

```
@IBAction func clearLastPin(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    newAnnotationCount = self.mapView.annotations.count - 1
    //prints for testing
    print("pressed")
    print("new",newAnnotationCount)
    print("mapView",self.mapView.annotations.count)
    if newAnnotationCount != 0{
        print("if statement entered")
        annotation = self.mapView.annotations[self.mapView.annotations.count - 1]
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}

@IBAction func clearPins(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    newAnnotationCount = self.mapView.annotations.count - 1
    print("pressed")
    while newAnnotationCount != 0{
        print("while statement entered")
        annotation = self.mapView.annotations[self.mapView.annotations.count - 1]
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        newAnnotationCount = newAnnotationCount - 1
    }
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
    //1
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //the app will dismiss the presented search controller
    //map view will look for any previously drawn annotation on the map and remove it


    //2
    //the ‘naturalLanguageQuery’ is very important in order to look up for -even an incomplete- addresses and POI (point of interests) like
    //restaurants, Coffeehouse, etc.
    localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text //transforming the search bar text into a natural language query
    localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
    localSearch.start { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in

        if localSearchResponse == nil{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Place Not Found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        //3
        //If the search API returns a valid coordinates for the place, then the app will instantiate a 2D point and draw it on the map within 
        //a pin annotation view
        self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        self.pointAnnotation.title = searchBar.text
        self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.latitude, longitude:     localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.longitude)


        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)

        //: zooms in on coordinate of found location
        /*
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01) // how far zoomed in
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.latitude, localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.longitude) // users location
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span) // links the two, I guess

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true) // maps region is equal to region we just made
        */

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I would not assume that `annotations` will honor the order that you add annotations. 2. You should be aware that the array of annotations may also include the `MKUserLocation` annotation (if you're showing that on the map). 3. Your `clearLastPin` and `clearPins` are dangerously starting at `newAnnotationCount = annotations.count - 1`. You really want to start at `annotations.count` and I'd make this a local variable. If `count` was zero, bad things would result. 4. You should not be instantiating a `MKPinAnnotationView` in your search routine. The `mapView(_:viewFor:)` should do that.

Comment: I am including user location so that's what the minus one is for. Even if the deleting of pins may appear random, how come it doesn't consistently delete any pin? Because it tries to delete the user location perhaps? Maybe I create my own array and pass the pins in as they are created, not including user location. What do you think?

Comment: Yeh, if you remove the user location annotation, it will add it back for you (thought sometimes with occassional weird UI artifacts and sometimes not). It's much safer for you to maintain your own list of annotations that you want to manage, methinks. (Or iterate through all the map view's annotations and check the annotation type.)